# Split Screen In Two (Horizontally or Vertically)

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to build a screen that is split down the middle horizontally when in landscape and vertically when in portrait.  I have tried the below, but it does not work like I was expecting.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <ListView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/lvChoices"
            android:layout_gravity="left" android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="horizontal">
        <ListView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/lvOptions"
            android:layout_gravity="right" android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To split down the middle exactly it is better to use `android:layout_weight="1"` to your each child in your main linear layout
To separate landscape and portrait.

1. you can use to xml file one in `layout-land` and other `layout-port` with `android:orientation="horizontal"` and `android:orientation="vertical"` respectively
2. If you wish to use same xml for both by setting your activity with `android:configChanges="orientation"`, then identify your LinearLayout with its id and  use `setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL)`  in the `onConfigurationChanged` function